# With reference to the Lifting of Hamiltonian cycles

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups, cayley-graphs, hamiltonicity

Can someone please help to understand about the concept of "lifting Hamiltonian cycles (in Cayley graphs)"?

As an example how the existence of a  Hamiltonian cycle is shown by using the concept of lifting Hamiltonian cycles in the Cayley graph of $\mathbb{Z}_7 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_3$ (A Cayley graph with respect to a generating set $S$ of the form $S=\{u,t\}$, where $|u|=7, |t|=3$). ?

I have inserted an image of a Cayley graph of the semidirect product $\mathbb{Z}_7 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_3$ under the above mentioned type of generating set. I have drawn it so that the 7-cycles and 3-cycles are clearly visible (Vertices lablelled 1-7, 8-14, 15-21 represent 7-cycles).

Is it possible to mention, with the aid of the labelling of the vertices a corresponding Hamiltonian cycle in the quotient graph that will be lifted and how the lifting occurs?

[image: Figure 1]

Please help with this question. Thanks a lot in advance.

In the paper of the following link they have employed this concept. In 3rd page it is mentioned as Marusic's method and they are thinking about a Hamiltonian cycle in the quotient Cayley graph and extending it to a cycle in the whole graph.

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=cayley+graphs+with+cyclic+commutator&btnG=#d=gs_qabs&u=%23p%3Dzi8JKNfz5HAJ

Then is it possible to help me to see and understand it from the example figure I have given.

Comment: I think this question is a little bit unclear. What means lifting in your case? What quotient graph you are talking about here specifically? Where do you take your terminology from? Maybe some source might help.

Comment: Thanks a lot @M.Winter. I have edited the question now with more details, can you please help? If it's not very clear please be kind enough to tell me, I will try to include more details according to my knowledge.

Comment: By lifting they consider the extension of the Hamiltonian cycle identified from the quotient Cayley graph to the whole graph.

Comment: Thanks a lot again :)

Comment: An answer from anyone is ok, please don't mind the mentioning as "Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources"